# 20.04 LTS server used as my NAS lost all network connectivity while I was away

Tags: networking, network-manager, ping

I am having the strangest issue. I lost network access over the weekend on my ubuntu 20.04.1 NAS/5.4.0-48 kernel. My board is a Supermicro x8sil-f model running a xeon and 16gb ram. It has been running fine for the last few months or so. I recently got it setup with transmission-openvpn-docker and it was working smoothly there too, I was able to transfer roughly 10-20gb the last month. I may have done an apt-get update and apt-get upgrade in the past week but that's about the only changes I can think of prior to the issue occurring.

The error is presenting itself is a complete loss of network connectivity, I can ping the NIC's ip and the loopback ip of 127.0.0.1 but anytime I try to ping anything external of the NIC, like say my gateway or any device on the LAN or 8.8.8.8 I get an error for each ping sent.

I am not very familiar with which logs are related to networking. So what I did try though was to peek around in /var/log/syslog and I found a bunch of systemd-resolved[2389] using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 1.1.1.1 or my LAN based pihole ip of 192.168.1.223, these appear every 3 seconds to maybe every 10 seconds. Is this maybe related?

I ran the `lsmod` command and do see the e1000e driver listed. I've also tried a `lshw -C net` the hw and and logical name are showing there as enp5s0, which is correct. It does strangely say what appears to me like the enp5s0 is *-network DISABLED for the port. I have tried DHCP/manual IPs on both ports and neither seem to work there too. If I look in the GUI under XFCE when clicking the network connections it shows ethernet network (intel 82574L) device not managed.

I just ran `dpkg --list | grep linux-image` and I have about 9 different versions 5.4.0-33.37 - 5.4.0-48-52 and I just tried booting with a previous version of the kernel and still no dice. I just used a USB wifi adapter. It shows connected to my AP. I am using DHCP and it shows it has an ip with `ip a` command, so it successfully grabbed an ip from my DHCP server, however the same error applies to pinging here, if I try to ping anything external, my gateway, another machine, etc I receive the same error for each ping. I can however ping 127.0.0.1 and the DHCP ip for the wifi usb from the server and they are successful. I ran an angry ip scan and also tried pinging the ip from a different machine, those all still fail.

Sorry about the wall of text but I am at a complete loss. I'm a bit of a newb, if anyone can be of some assistance to me and this issue I will be forever grateful.

Thanks!

Netplan config:

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enp4s0:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.1.177/24
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 192.168.1.223
        - 1.1.1.1
  version: 2
```

Edit: I made the changes you suggested Artur, this is what my yaml looks like now.

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enp4s0:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.1.176/24
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 1.1.1.1
    enp5s0:
      dhcp4: yes
  version: 2
```

The above worked for the enp5s0!! Now I do use this machine as a server. Do you think I should play around with adding a manual ip for enp5s0?

Comment: Can you try and post the contents of your netplan config? `cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`

Comment: Yes definitely, and thanks so much for helping me look in to this.

`# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enp4s0:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.1.177/24
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 192.168.1.223
        - 1.1.1.1
  version: 2`

Comment: Please post it with proper formatting in the question (edit the original question to add this). Thanks.

Comment: Ok a few things: The network adapter in the config is called `enp4s0`, but in the question you refer to `enp5s0`. Furthermore you set the static IP `192.168.1.177`, with `192.168.1.1` as gateway - this should work. Finally, I see you have a local DNS server running at `192.168.1.223`, correct?

Comment: Are there any additional files in `/etc/netplan/` (run `ls /etc/netplan/`)?

Comment: Sorry, I believe that was a typo. I was for certain on the enp4s0 port originally and have it configured for a static IP. I am plugged in to that port now. enp5s0 is set to DHCP but isn't working either, I have tested that port a couple of times too. 

Regarding DNS, yes my pihole is at 192.168.1.223 and gateway is 192.168.1.1. I will say though, that I rarely browse the web or transfer traffic outside of the LAN.

And I can confirm the only file within `/etc/netplan/` is 00-installer-config.yaml

Comment: I would try this: Take backup of you existing `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`, just in case. Add `enp5s0`and next line `dhcp4: true` under the `networks` section (remember correct indentation, check [netplan.io](https://netplan.io/examples/) for examples). Then run `netplan apply`, and see if you get connectivity if you connect to the `enp5s0` interface.

Comment: Thanks Artur, I had to go in to work but at lunch I will test this. I will update then.

Comment: Artur, that definitely got the 2nd NIC functioning. Now I am going to try and apply the same manual ip I was using for enp4s0 for enp5s0. See if it accepts that. Any idea what may have caused the enp4s0 to react this way?

Comment: I'm adding the troubleshooting steps as an answer, if you get it to work please upvote! :-)

Comment: Thanks again so much and I do believe you are correct. I applied the manual ip to enp5s0 and it is pinging that ip correctly from a host and from the server. So thanks for doing all of that work. I will most definitely upvote and mark it solved if I can. Take care and good day!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following steps to troubleshoot:

- Try a different hardware connection to the `enp4s0` (cable, port etc) - maybe it's a hardware malfunction.
- Try to add the two lines about `enp5s0` in your netplan config, and run `netplan apply`

  ```
  # This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
  network:
    ethernets:
      enp4s0:
        addresses:
        - 192.168.1.177/24
        gateway4: 192.168.1.1
        nameservers:
          addresses:
          - 192.168.1.223
          - 1.1.1.1
      enp5s0:
        dhcp4: true
    version: 2
  ```

This will add dhcp4 to the NIC `enp5s0` so you can test if that interface connects.

If it works, I also imagine `enp5s0` would work with the static IP settings you currently have for `enp4s0` with the following netplan config:

```
   # This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
   network:
     ethernets:
       enp5s0:
         addresses:
         - 192.168.1.177/24
         gateway4: 192.168.1.1
         nameservers:
           addresses:
           - 192.168.1.223
           - 1.1.1.1
     version: 2
```

Good luck!